# Get photos from flickr.photos API?

Tags: flickr

I want to list photos from flickr account using flickr.photos API using PHP with OAuth.

Right now to get the URLs of the images I am doing it in 2 steps which makes too many requests to the API and takes too much time:

1. First I request the photos using `flickr.photos.search`
2. then I loop the array of results and call the `flickr.photos.getInfo` for each photo apart. 
   [result of `flickr.photos.search`] does not return URL of images, but getInfo does.

Is there a way to get the images with one single request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the solution, described here: [Flickr Image URLs](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html)

> You can construct the source URL to a photo once you know its ID, server ID, farm ID and secret, as returned by many API methods.

The URL takes the following format:

```
http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg
    or
http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}_[mstzb].jpg
    or
http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{o-secret}_o.(jpg|gif|png)
```

You can find examples and image size prefixes as well on the source page.

Comment: In this, how define it is 'jpg' or 'gif' or 'png'? Before this, we calling getPhotos($user_id, $args); This function is not return the extension. Any other method to get extension of the file?

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning use Angular,
There is an npm package that make you the job.

Checkout it on npm site:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-flickr-api-factory